# I can't import request in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, request, babeljs

Everytime I try to import request like `var request = require('request');` or `import request from 'request';` it always gives me this error

```
in ./~/buffer/index.js
Module parse failed: C:\Users\User\Documents\js\react-app\node_modules\buffer\index.js Unexpected token (1216:24)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1216:24)
 @ ./~/safe-buffer/index.js 2:13-30
```

I have tried installing babel-preset-es2015, updating request versions and babel versions.

**.babelrc** :

```
{"presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]}
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'output'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
         })
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why are you using deprecated node only module for your client side project? You could simply use `fetch` instead or `cross-fetch` if you have some sort of an SSR.

Comment: I was following a tutorial to try to use request. I'll use fetch then, thank you for telling